# Permission denied error while opening/copying a file and permissions listed with question marks

Tags: 16.04, permissions, files, copy

I have a file with unknown permissions

```
sudo ls -la 
-????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? desktop.ini
```

I am unable to to open/copy this file (even to the same directory).

```
sudo cat desktop.ini
cat: desktop.ini: Permission denied
```

And I am not able to do any operation on this file:

```
sudo chmod u+rw desktop.ini 
chmod: cannot access 'desktop.ini': Permission denied
```

In the GUI

**Properties > Permissions > The permissions of desktop.ini could not be determined**

Why can't I do anything with this file?

Comment: `desktop.ini` is a Windows thing I guess. Does the file exists in some other partition?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: As written, this question could perhaps be closed as a duplicate of [Why do question mark characters appear when changing the permissions of directory?](//askubuntu.com/q/243999) but it seem like you are trying to edit a file on Windows' partition for some reason and there may well be a better way of achieving what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use other OS(i,e Windows) in virtual Machines to access/open/copy the file. Succeed!.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo chown root:root desktop.ini
sudo chmod 777 desktop.ini
```

By the way, this file is on another disk? If yes make sure the disk is mounted as read-write.

Comment: sudo chown root:root desktop.ini 
chown: cannot access 'desktop.ini': Permission denied

Comment: desktop.ini is on a different disk than the one you're running ubuntu on?

Comment: Yes, it is on other disk.

Comment: The disk is already mounted as rw. I can  read/write other files in same dir.